# filter function error :: Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child .... use an array instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to display results after applying filter function.I need to compare with searchValue.but it gives Error

```
{noteList.filter((obj,index) => <Card 
                noteObj={obj.Name.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue)} 
                index={index} 
                deleteNote={deleteNote}
                updateNoteArray={updateNoteArray}
             />)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `map` not `filter`

```
{ noteList
.filter((obj, index)=>{ return obj.Name.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue)})
.map((obj,index) => <Card 
                noteObj={obj} 
                index={index} 
                deleteNote={deleteNote}
                updateNoteArray={updateNoteArray}
             />)
}
```

Comment: But i need to filter according to searchValue

Comment: @MShushant see my edit

Answer (score 3):

You need to first **filter** out the options from `noteList` array according to your condition and then apply a `map` over it.

```js
{
noteList.filter((obj) => obj.Name.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue))
        .map((item,index) => <Card 
                noteObj={item} 
                index={index} 
                deleteNote={deleteNote}
                updateNoteArray={updateNoteArray}
             />
 )
}
```

`noteList.filter((obj)=>obj.Name.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue))`
This will return a new array which contains all the **names** which will includes **searchValue**. Then you can use this resultant array to display your result

Comment: Thank You soo much.Earlier i made some typo in this and was facing Error. Your Solution Worked.